# Exporting Cloudwatch Logs to S3 using Lambda

Tags: amazon-s3, lambda

I have some logs in CloudWatch and everyday, I keep getting new logs. Now, I want to store today's and yesterday's logs in Cloud Watch itself but logs that are 2 days older have to be moved to S3.

I have tried using the below code to export CloudWatch Logs to S3 :

```
import boto3
import collections

region = 'us-east-1'

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    s3 = boto3.client('s3')

    response = s3.create_export_task(
        taskName='export_task',
        logGroupName='/aws/lambda/test2',
        logStreamNamePrefix='2016/11/29/',
        fromTime=1437584472382,
        to=1437584472402,
        destination='prudhvi1234',
        destinationPrefix='AWS'
    )

    print response
```

When I run this, I got the following error :

```
'S3' object has no attribute 'create_export_task': AttributeError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 10, in lambda_handler
    response = s3.create_export_task(
AttributeError: 'S3' object has no attribute 'create_export_task'
```

What might the mistake be?

Comment: Why don't you use `create_export_task`? http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/logs.html#CloudWatchLogs.Client.create_export_task

Comment: That's because you're trying to call `create_export_task()` method on s3 client. It's not S3 client method, it's `logs` client method. Replace `s3 = boto3.client('s3')` with `logs_client = boto3.client('logs')` and then in the following line replace `response = s3.create_export_task(` with `response = logs_client.create_export_task(`.

Comment: You have `fromTime` and `to` in your method call, these are UNIX timestamps that tell your function which log entries to export. Calculate them in your Lambda function on each run based on current timestamp.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129832/discussion-between-prudhvi-and-michal-gasek).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
client = boto3.client('logs')
```

You are accessing logs from CloudWatch and not S3. Hence the error.
Subsequently

```
response = client.create_export_task(
        taskName='export_task',
        logGroupName='/aws/lambda/test2',
        logStreamNamePrefix='2016/11/29/',
        fromTime=1437584472382,
        to=1437584472402,
        destination='prudhvi1234',
        destinationPrefix='AWS'
    )
```

http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/logs.html#CloudWatchLogs.Client.create_export_task

checkout this link for more information

Comment: The first line in this answer is the answer, in the question this line is wrong